# Copy text from Android AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is there any way to make the text in an [`AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) "selectable" or "copyable" in Android? Or do I have to use some other widget instead of `AlertDialog`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This can be achieved several ways. But first, to customize the dialog more, you'll need to use the [`AlertDialog.Builder`-class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) to [create your custom dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog). This can then be populated by your own `View`s.

Here are three methods of how you can archive your selectable text:

### Using Android 3.0 +

Since API-Level 11 (Android 3.0), the `TextView` has a method called [`setTextIsSelectable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextIsSelectable%28boolean%29), which pretty much looks like what I achieved by hacking around as detailed below.

```
// The TextView to show your Text
TextView showText = new TextView(this);
showText.setText("Some selectable text goes here.");
showText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// Build the Dialog
builder.setView(showText)
       .setTitle("Selectable text")
       .setCancelable(true)
       .show();
```

The problem with this solution is, that it will only work on devices running Android 3.0 and higher, while the other two solutions will also work on Android 1.5 (I used Android 2.2).

### Copy to Clipboard

Since the purpose of marking text is (most of the time) to copy it, you can simply add an `onLongClickListener` or a simple `onClickListener` (the one you like the most) to the `TextView` and copy its displayed text to the System's clipboard.

Little illustration of this:

```
// Get our tools
AlertDialog dialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
// The TextView to show your Text
TextView showText = new TextView(this);
showText.setText("Some selectable text goes here.");
// Add the Listener
showText.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Copy the Text to the clipboard
        ClipboardManager manager = 
            (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        TextView showTextParam = (TextView) v;
        manager.setText( showTextParam.getText() );
        // Show a message:
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Text in clipboard",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
        return true;
    }
});
// Build the Dialog
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(showText);
dialog = builder.create();
// Some eye-candy
dialog.setTitle("Selectable text");
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show();
```

This example will copy all the displayed text in the systems clipboard.

### Make an `EditText` look like a `TextView`

Since there is no really easy way to make the Text of a `TextView` selectable on Android versions before 3.0, you can use an `EditText` (which has selectable text by default) and make it look like a `TextView`.

This needs some XML-Layout (to get the `TextView`'s style) but probably gets you the most native look and feel:

#### The XML-Part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Make the EditText look like a TextView -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/showText"
        style="?android:attr/textViewStyle"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### The Java-Part:

```
// Get our tools
AlertDialog dialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
// The EditText to show your Text
LayoutInflater inflater = 
    (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog,
        (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.showText));
EditText showText = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.showText);
showText.setText("Some selectable text goes here.");
// Build the Dialog
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(layout);
dialog = builder.create();
// Some eye-candy
dialog.setTitle("Selectable text");
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show();
```

Some customizations and eye-candy might be added to the result ;)

I hope this gives you an idea of how you can achieve this task. It's late now, time for bed.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit hackish because it assumes you know the default AlertDialog layout (see [Where can I find default AlertDialog layout xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314912/where-can-i-find-default-alertdialog-layout-xml-file)), but if you want to go this way, you could do the following thing:

```
    alertDialog.show();
    try {
        TextView textView = (TextView)dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // Oups!
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could place an EditText in your AlertDialog.  If you didn't want it to seem like there's a textbox in there, you could just style it like the background of the AlertDialog to make it blend in.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Hopefully that helps, if not, I can try to provide other means of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but here is the best solution i have used so far:

```
//..... creating the AlertDialog and showing it.
dialog.show();
// after showing it, we fetch the message TextView container
View messageView = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
if (messageView instanceof TextView) {
    ((TextView) messageView).setTextIsSelectable(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MaterialAlertDialog you can update the style easily.

1. Set `materialAlertDialogTheme` to `MyMaterialAlertDialog`.

```
    <style name="MyActivityOrDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/MyMaterialAlertDialog</item>
        ...
    </style>
```

2. Set `materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle` to `MyMaterialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle`.

```
    <style name="MyMaterialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialAlertDialog">
        <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/MyMaterialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle</item>
    </style>
```

Then you will be able to update the bodyText's `android:textIsSelectable` to `true`.

```
    <style name="MyMaterialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.Material3.Body.Text">
        <item name="android:textIsSelectable">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Btw, the above `findViewById(android.R.id.message)` solution doesn't work for `MaterialAlertDialog`.