# Where can I find default AlertDialog layout xml file?

Tags: android, layout, android-alertdialog

I want to make an default Alert Dialog with a small modification. Where can I find an xml layout file of default AlertDialog?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

All default layouts are included in the Android SDK.  In your SDK installation, see the following:

```
<SDK_INTALL_DIRECTORY>/sdk/platforms/android-18/data/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml
```

(or replace "android-18" with the API level you want).

Note that you will only see API levels that you have downloaded via the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: why can't i access it by android.R.layout.alert_dialog ?

Comment: @YTerle I think it's private

Comment: See this to find SDK_INSTALL_DIRECTORY https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176594/android-sdk-location